# Proxy Server - modify header of request

Tags: c#, header, proxy

How do I develop an application that modifies all requests to server, listens to local ports, adds headers, and then transfers between client and server?

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Some code example would be nice.

Comment: i googled.i had found third party application named `fiddler` but i want pure code in c#

Comment: We don't simply hand-over the code to ypu. Did you already start on your HttpListener? And your HttpWebRequest methods? Give that a try first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab a copy of mentalis: http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/proxy/

It supports SOCKS4/5 as well as HTTP proxy. You can take a look at the source and figure it out - its not that hard.

[EDIT - and if you're specifically looking at implementing SOCKS, you should read the protocol definition: http://www.openssh.org/txt/socks4.protocol. Theres really only one message you need to implement in a basic proxy (CONNECT) and all you do is parse the target IP/port, open a socket and start relaying data to the incoming socket that sent the request.]